# Complex conditions (AND/OR) in the new authorization model - ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-identity

I am having difficulties solving the authorization logic in ASP.NET Core when there are complex `AND/OR` conditions to handle. An example of conditions to check before my API methods get authorized:

```
A & (B | C & D & E | C & F)    - each condition consists of 1 or more checks
```

I am aware of all the authorization types available (including [policy-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies) and [resource-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased)).

In general, using the new authorization model, I am not sure how to go about the `OR` conditions.

I understood that I could have authorization handlers for `OR` conditions, but feels to me this is not enough (in my example, I don't think I can create one requirement with 3 authorization handlers for `(B) | (C & D & E) | (C & F)` because will be too clunky, especially if these conditions do not make sense to be brought together due to the business model rules).

I also understood that authorization handlers cannot depend to one another. Also, I think one handler cannot be associated more generically to multiple requirements.

Are there other ways to handle these conditions? Is there a general rule how to break the complexity into small simple pieces to tackle such problems?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating your own middleware + custom attribute to handle such cases. Also, you will need to define binary enums to handle such rules:

```
[CustomAuthorization(GroupA.A | GroupB.A & GroupC.D))]
```

Comment: Thanks, any pointers where to start from? Some good links for any custom authorization middlewares?

Comment: Try to start from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: And this is also good point to start: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/10/creating-custom-middleware-asp-net-core/